# Sum of the last four digits of $3^{2015}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $N = 3^{2015}$, what is the sum of the last four digits of $N$?

$(A)21$ $(B)22$ $(C)23$ $(D)24$

It is not possible using a calculator, so how can I do it? Hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A variation, I think a bit simpler, of ADG's answer.  We have
$$\eqalign{
  3^{2015}
  &=3\times(10-1)^{1007}\cr
  &=\color{red}{3}\left(10^{1007}-\cdots-\binom{1007}410^4+{}\right.\cr
  &\qquad\qquad\left.{}+\color{red}{\binom{1007}310^3-\binom{1007}210^2+1007\times10-1}\right)\cr}$$
and all except the red parts are irrelevant.

---

For the remaining calculations, we only need the last digit of $\binom{1007}3$, so
$$\binom{1007}3=\frac{1007\times1006\times1005}{3\times2\times1}
  =1007\times503\times335=\underbrace{\cdots\ \cdots\ \cdots}_{\rm irrelevant\ digits}\cdots5\ .$$
Likewise
$$\binom{1007}{2}=1007\times503=\cdots21\ .$$
So, without using a calculator at any stage, the last four digits of the number are given by (hover to see the answer)

> $$3\times(5000-2100+70-1)=8907$$

and the total is

> $$24\ .$$

Comment: please do the caluclation explicitly if you want to say if it's simpler.

Comment: @ADG IMHO it's already very clear that my method is simpler.  However I have added the calculations as you request.

Answer (score 3):

Use Binomial Theorem and actually it's easy because every multiplication needs only last four digits and some digits' calculation is reduced by the already present zeroes:
$$\newcommand{\c}[2]{{}^{#1}{\mathbb C}_{#2}}
3^{2015}=27.3^{4\times 503}=27(80+1)^{503}=27\sum_{k=0}^{503}\c{503}k80^k
\\=27(\underbrace{1+\c{503}180+\c{503}280^2+\c{503}380^3}_{\text{useful}}+...)$$
OK here 1 zero is already present so calculate last 3 digits only:
$$\c{503}180=503*80=40240=\_0240$$
OK here 2 zeroes are already present so calculate last 2 digits only:
$$\c{503}280^2=\frac12*503*502*6400=503*251*6400
\\=\_03*51*64(00)=\_53*64(00)=\_9200$$
OK here 3 zeroes are already present so calculate last 1 digits only:
$$\c{503}280^2=\frac16*503*502*501*512000=503*251*167*512000
\\=\_3*1*7*2(000)=\_2000$$
So:
$$3^{2015}=27(1+\_0240+\_9200+\_2000)=27*\_1441=\_8907$$
Sum is:
$$8+9+7=8*3=24$$

Comment: Options given are (A)21 (B)22 (C)23 (D)24. I don't think any if the following will come. Though I am still trying so please wait before giving full answer I want to do it myself.

Comment: @Freddy D is the correct.

Answer (score 1):

We have $3^{\phi(1000)}=3^{400}\equiv 1\pmod{1000}$, hence $3^{2015}\equiv 3^{15}\pmod{1000}$. The latter can be computed by repeated squaring modulo $1000$.

Comment: But surely this will only (easily) give the last three digits?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is D 24 the first four digits are 8907

I used BT to solve the question

$$3^{2015}=-3(1-10)^{1007}=-3(1-10*1007+100*1007*1006/2-1000*1007*10066*1005/6+........)$$
$$3^{2015}=-3(1-10)^{1007}=-3(1-70+2100-5000)$$
$$3^{2015}=-3(1-10)^{1007}=-3(-2969)=8907$$

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). $$\lambda(10\ 000)=\lambda(2^45^4)=\text{lcm}(\lambda(2^4),\lambda(5^4))=\text{lcm}\left(\frac{1}{2}\phi(2^4),\phi(5^4)\right)=\text{lcm}(4,500)=500$$

$$3^{2015}\equiv 3^{2015\pmod {\lambda(10\ 000)}}\equiv 3^{2015\pmod{500}}\equiv 3^{15}\equiv 8907\pmod {10\, 000}$$